# her former flame’s new girlfriend - what does "flame" mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/tsarnaev-boston-marathon-bombing-legal-woes-140543802.html

> On Aug. 25, a New York City woman caught up in a messy child custody battle with her ex-boyfriend got into a fight on the phone with her former **flame**’s new girlfriend. According to the police, heated words were exchanged, and the girlfriend, who also has a child with the man, was subsequently arrested and charged with harassment after she allegedly threatened the other woman’s life.

What does that word mean in this context?

Comment: Hello - you should consult a dictionary or two before asking questions here. [flame](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flame) give you the definition. You may wish to use something like [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=flame&ls=a) that searches multiple dictionaries. Questions that can be answered entirely with a dictionary are **off-topic** and tend to get closed rather quickly.

Comment: To add to jimsug's comment: The top three dictionary hits on the Google for `"flame" definition` (and yes, the code formatting is deliberate) all contained the definion you are looking for when I tried it. I tend to be cautious about dictionary closures, but the resources available after a lookup aren't really ambiguous in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "flame" is an informal word for a sweetheart/lover. See [definition 5](http://thefreedictionary.com/flame).  It is generally used in the context that you provide, that is to say a "former flame" or an "[old flame](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+old+flame)". The latter is a common phrase.